# Is there a way to capture a specific error within an exception?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

By specific exception I mean differentiating between the same exception but different errors from the same exception rather than differentiating between different exceptions completely, for example:

With the `ZeroDivisionError` exception, there are multiple errors. One of which being:

```
>> 0/0
>> ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

And another being:

```
>> 0**-1
>> ZeroDivisionError: 0.0 cannot be raised to a negative power
```

Same exception, different errors.

I want to only except one type of error which is the 0 to a negative power error and pass it, but with any other `ZeroDivisionError` I want to re-raise the error but with an empty message.

The first thing I tried was:

```
try:... # Some code
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    if e!="0.0 cannot be raised to a negative power":
        raise ZeroDivisionError("")
```

But that wouldn't work, no other errors being raised, just simply wouldn't work.

So I started investigating and found out that `e` is not a string type but instead a `ZeroDivisionError` type.

So if you do this:

```
try:print(0/0)
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    print(type(e))
```

The output would be:
`<class 'ZeroDivisionError'>`

So in my second attempt I did the same thing as before but instead compared `e` to a certain `ZeroDivisionError` type error:

```
try:... # Some code
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    if e!=ZeroDivisionError("0.0 cannot be raised to a negative power"):
        raise ZeroDivisionError("")
```

But again, same way as before, didn't work.

So one last thing came to me which was including the error string when excepting the exception:

```
try:... # Some code
except ZeroDivisionError("0.0 cannot be raised to a negative power"):
    raise ZeroDivisionError("")
```

But anticipating failure, it failed.

So.. is it possible? Or can you only except certain exceptions no matter what error within the exception?

Comment: You can check if `str(e)` is equal to a particular message, if that is what you want.

Comment: @khelwood Good idea, I'll try it, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, you need to use `str(e)` or `e.args[0]`

Comment: @DeepSpace Can you explain how e.args[0] works?

Comment: @DeepSpace @khelwood Thanks a lot, it works, all I had to do was convert `e` to a string